# How to calculate the Impedance of a Shielded Differential Connector

Tags: connector, impedance, differential

I am working on a project involved with a shielded differential connector ,the connector interface as shown,and my question are:

1. Is there any formula to calculate the impedance ?there is a formula that can briefly calculate the strip line impedance or conductors spacing impedance ,but this type is a circular shield wrapped around the dielectric, maybe Simulation is a good way, but is there a formula?
   [image]
2. My second question is when an STP cable terminates into such the connector ,a short length of it is untwisted for mounting onto the connector and the region of the untwisted wires will raise the impedance ,does the raised impedance will impact the signal integrity?can I calculate the raised impedance?

Comment: Don't post some random undimensioned picture - that is no help at all. You need to add a hyperlink to the part in question. Sure there are formulas but you need to help your situation by providing information.